# pygame, how can I use sprite.Group.draw() to draw all sprites?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am learning pygame by making a simple game.
Here is the code:
Main script:

```
import pygame
from gracz2 import SpriteGenerator

BLACK = ( 0, 0, 0)
WHITE = ( 255, 255, 255)
GREEN = ( 0, 255, 0)
RED = ( 255, 0, 0)
BLUE = ( 0, 0, 255)

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Super Gra!")
screen_height = 720
screen_width = 1280
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
playerSprite = SpriteGenerator(1,150,150)
playerSprite.rect.x = (screen_width/2 - 75)
playerSprite.rect.y = 550
all_sprites_list.add(playerSprite)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
mainloop = True
playtime = 0

while mainloop:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # User presses QUIT-button.
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            mainloop = False 
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # User presses ESCAPE-Key
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                mainloop = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        playerSprite.moveLeft(8)
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        playerSprite.moveRight(8)

    milliseconds = clock.tick(60) 
    playtime += milliseconds / 1000.0
    all_sprites_list.update()

    pygame.display.set_caption("Czas gry: " + str(round(playtime,1)) + " sekund")

    # Refresh the screen
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    screen.blit(playerSprite.image, (playerSprite.rect.x,playerSprite.rect.y))
    pygame.display.flip()

print(all_sprites_list.sprites())
print(all_sprites_list)
print(playerSprite.rect.x)
print(playerSprite.rect.y)
pygame.quit()
```

and another file called "gracz2.py":

```
import pygame
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = ( 0, 0, 0)

class SpriteGenerator(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #This class represents a player. It derives from the "Sprite" class in Pygame.

    def __init__(self, type, width, height):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Pass in the color of the player, and its x and y position, width and height.
        # Set the background color and set it to be transparent
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)


        if type == 1:
            self.image = pygame.image.load("sprite-ufo.gif").convert_alpha()
        elif type == 2:
            self.image = pygame.image.load("sprite-bomb.jpg").convert_alpha()

        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def moveRight(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x += pixels

    def moveLeft(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x -= pixels
```

It could be done in one file but the code is more readable for me this way.
around line 50 i call `all_sprites_list.draw(screen)`
which to my understanding should blit all the sprites contained in `all_sprites_list` but it does nothing.
I have to use `screen.blit(playerSprite.image, (playerSprite.rect.x,playerSprite.rect.y))`
to manually blit the sprite.
As i am going to add generate lots of sprites later i can't blit them all manually.
Why doesn't `all_sprites_list.draw(screen)` work as intended?
It's probably a stupid mistake in the code but I am trying to find for over an hour now and I am unable to locate it.

Comment: on list you have only playerSprite which you later draw manually in the same place - what if you add more objects to group ?

Comment: to center on screen you can use `playerSprite.rect.center = screen.get_rect().center` To horiziontal center `playerSprite.rect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx`

Comment: code works for me - when I remove `screen.blit(playerSprite.image, ...)` I still see player on screen because group draws it. Linux Mint, Python 3.7, PyGame 1.9.6 (PL: u mnie kod działa  - jak wyrzuce `screen.blit(playerSprite.image, ...)` to wciąż widzę gracza bo został narysowany przez grupę.)

Comment: BTW: you can draw using `rect` - `screen.blit(playerSprite.image, playerSprite.rect)` - and this is what `Group` does with all elements on list.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that when i restart my PC the draw() function works fine.
I don't know what caused it first, sorry for asking without following the first rule of IT troubleshooting first (restart and try again)
PS: thank you furas for your answers